# Is there a significant difference between using the tornado's AsyncHTTPClient v.s. wrapping blocking http calls in run_in_executor()?

Tags: asynchronous, tornado, asynchttpclient

I am attempting to use the library `s3fs` in a `tornado` application. The easiest approach would be to make a small function that fetches some data from s3 (using `s3fs`) and wrap that in `run_in_executor()`.

Is there any advantage to writing a custom library to fetch from s3 using tornado's `AsyncHTTPClient` instead?

(Note: I am aware of botoaio and others. For my particular use-case I require the output to be in the format provided by `s3fs`.)

Comment: `AsyncHTTPClient` will be more performant than `run_in_executor`. But for low to medium traffic applications, I don't think there will be much difference. You can still run multiple tornado processes to compensate for that. Probably, start with `run_in_executor` and if and when performance becomes an issue, invest your time in writing an asynchronous client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AsyncHTTPClient is more *efficient* than running a synchronous library with run_in_executor. The difference is mainly the memory needed for thread stacks at high levels of concurrency. Performance will generally be similar as long as you have enough threads and memory for your level of concurrency. So unless you're doing a lot of s3 operations in parallel, there's little reason to invest a lot of work in converting everything to async interfaces.